# All of <a> tags were broken on outlook

Tags: email, outlook, smtp, html-email, amazon-ses

All of  tags are changed to the below type of string on outlook web browser

```
[www.frimetime.com/verify/9026151fe8ddd0db4a9cb84e2ac0e7ce1a07ccd1be100896b2772e620b74ac16]Verify Now
```

It has to be.

```
<a href="www.frimetime.com/verify/9026151fe8ddd0db4a9cb84e2ac0e7ce1a07ccd1be100896b2772e620b74ac16">Verify Now</a>
```

** The thing is it is working on Google(web browser) or mailbox as well **

The email server is using AWS smtp service.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Outlook web will do that for any links that do not have a protocol at the start of the link, i.e. http:// or https://.

I.e. you need `<a href="https://www.frimetime.com/verify/9026151fe8ddd0db4a9cb84e2ac0e7ce1a07ccd1be100896b2772e620b74ac16">Verify Now</a>`